# F# pattern-matching gone wrong

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I am just starting out with F# so this might be a trivial question but I am not able to understand why the pattern matching in my code acts as it does.

Quick explanation of the code:
The func **calcNextMatch** should recurse a list and if 2 elements are equal they should be added together.
In the end the func should return a number that is the addition of all digits that has a match with the next digit in the list.
f.ex. [1;3;2;2;5] should return 4

Code:

```
let rec printList l =
    match l with
    | head :: tail -> printf "%d " head; printList tail
    | [] -> printfn ""

let rec calcNextMatch list =
    printList list
    match list with
    | [] -> 0
    | _ :: tail ->            
        printList tail
        let h = Seq.head list
        let t = Seq.tryHead tail
        printfn "h: %i" h
        printfn "t: %O" t
        match t with
        | Some h -> 
            printfn "TAIL t: %i is equal to HEAD h: %i" t.Value h
            printfn "Calculation is: %i" (t.Value + h)
            (t.Value + h) + calcNextMatch tail
        | _ -> calcNextMatch tail

let sequence = [ 1;3;2;2;5 ]
let run = calcNextMatch sequence
```

When I run this code the problem is that the pattern-matching 
does not work as I expect it.
f.ex this print output from running the script.

```
h: 1
t: Some(3)
TAIL t: 3 is equal to HEAD h: 3
```

this means that F# has matched

```
match t with
        | Some h ->
```

in a case where t = Some(3) and h = 1
which translates to

```
match 3 with
        | Some 1 ->
```

and that I do not understand.
The print before the matching states the value of t and h to **3** and **1** but in the pattern-matching the value of **h** has change to **3**
How is this possible?

Comment: `Some h` is declaring a new variable `h`, not matching on the value of the existing variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pattern match against constant literals, otherwise the value get bounded as if was a new let-binding.

In these cases what you do normally is to add a `when` condition:

```
    match t with
    | Some x when x = h ->
```

Also notice that you can use pattern match further to simplify your code, for instance here:

```
| _ :: tail ->            
    printList tail
    let h = Seq.head list
```

You can write:

```
| h :: tail ->            
    printList tail
```

Also all this portion:

```
| _ :: tail ->            
    printList tail
    let h = Seq.head list
    let t = Seq.tryHead tail
    printfn "h: %i" h
    printfn "t: %O" t
    match t with
    | Some h -> 
        printfn "TAIL t: %i is equal to HEAD h: %i" t.Value h
        printfn "Calculation is: %i" (t.Value + h)
        (t.Value + h) + calcNextMatch tail
```

becomes:

```
| h :: tail ->            
    printList tail
    //printfn "h: %i" h
    //printfn "t: %O" t
    match tail with
    | t::_ when t = h -> 
        printfn "TAIL t: %i is equal to HEAD h: %i" t h
        printfn "Calculation is: %i" (t + h)
        (t + h) + calcNextMatch tail
```

And you can unify all matches in one, so your whole function becomes:

```
let rec calcNextMatch list =
    printList list
    match list with
    | [] -> 0
    | h::x::tail when x = h -> x + h + calcNextMatch (x::tail)
    | _::tail -> calcNextMatch tail
```

Finally, when you're done with debugging, you can remove the prints and since the last parameter of your function is the one you match against, you can use the keyword `function`, also use an `as` pattern to avoid reconstructing the list:

```
let rec calcNextMatch = function
    | [] -> 0
    | h::((x::_) as tail) when x = h -> x + h + calcNextMatch tail
    | _::tail -> calcNextMatch tail
```

Comment: thanks for the help and thorough explanation. I get it now.
I was also assuming that it was a matter of me not knowing F# does things.
Now my algo does what it is supposed to :-D